# Oxidising power of oxides of 15th group elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, redox, oxides

In case of oxides of 15th group elements in form of $\ce{M2O3}$ ($\ce{M}$ is the 15th group element), does oxidising power of oxides increase or decrease down the group?

I tried to check by comparing the standard reduction potential (SRP) values or other related issues but didn't find any reliable sources.